# JSP with JSTL not working on tomcat 8 in a Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot

I have include these dependency in pom.xml.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Still i am getting javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(Ljavax/el/ELContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;

I also included one more dependency in pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then the error changed to An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp at line 7 4: <%@ page session="false" %> [[[[ JSTL CODE USING EXPRESSION LANGUAGE]]]

Everything is working fine in eclipse ide but not working on deploying on separate tomcat  server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting below error because of the presence of **tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar** in your `Tomcat 8.0\webapps\AppName\WEB-INF\lib` folder.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(Ljavax/el/ELContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

This error is due to the conflict between the `ELSupport.class` provided by **Tomcat** and **tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar** present in the applications `lib` directory, hence you get that error in Tomcat. And it works fine in Eclipse since it uses embedded server.

To fix this issue add below code in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When you add `tomcat-embed-el` dependency as `scope=required` then the **tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar** will not be added into your `\AppName\WEB-INF\lib` folder.

For information check this [Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5454) on Spring-Boot's Github repository.

Also you can use these sample apps:

1. [Spring-Boot-Jsp-Demo](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/Spring-Boot-Jsp-Demo) configured with `InternalResourceViewResolver` bean.
2. [spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jsp](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jsp) configured with `application.properties` just like in the spring-boot sample apps.