# Whitelabel Error Page There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am following Spring in Action (part 2) and trying to create the Spittr application as the book shows. 
`(with Spring Tool Suite 7.3.7. and Maven.)`

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

> Whitelabel Error Page.
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Apr 07 16:21:23 CEST 2016
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp

The package structure is:

[image: image here]

As you see I tried to place the `/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp` in several places in, case there was a problem with the path.

DispatcherServlet Configuration Class:

```
package com.spittr.config;

import  org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }
}
```

WebConfig.java class:

```
package com.spittr.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.spitter.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");          
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
    DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

RootConfig.java class:
package com.spittr.config;

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"spitter"},
excludeFilters={
@Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)})
public class RootConfig {
}
```

The @Controller class.

```
package com.spittr.web;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController 
{
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=GET)
    public String home() 
    {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>spittr</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Spittr</name>
    <description>Test 1</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

home.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spittr</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css"
        href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to Spittr</h1>
            <a href="<c:url value="/spittles" />">Spittles</a> |
            <a href="<c:url value="/spitter/register" />">Register</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically is the same that you can find in the book. 
I simply don't know what else to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Problem is with your Project Structure, the `WEB-INF` should be under `src/main/webapp` and Not `src/main`.

That is, as per your `ViewResolver` your JSP file should be under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp`.

More info on [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Here is a [Spring Boot Sample App](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/Spring-Boot-Jsp-Demo).

PS: If you are planning to deploy this app in Tomcat then you'll face this [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938716/jsp-with-jstl-not-working-on-tomcat-8-in-a-spring-boot-application/), the above sample app resolves this issue.

Comment: Yeah Ok Nicely working. Seems I got too much to learn. Thanks.

Comment: My structure is correct and also pom.xml is correct( has all the required dependencies for tomcat) but still not returning the page. Controll is coming properly but it's not rendering the home.jsp page. Why this is happening??

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to make sure to add appropriate dependencies, by adding the eclipse compiler for JDT to pick the jsp file placed in src/main/WEB-INF/*/, and tomcat starter also.

As you already know you need to declare the jsp files location in the application.properties

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```