# Spring boot web app not running on tomcat 9

Tags: java, maven, jsp, spring-boot, tomcat

My web App works fine on Eclipse Photon STS, java 8 and Spring Boot 2.02 with the embeded tomcat using endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8081/DataViewer/tspsPatentSearch
```

But when I compile the code into  DataViewer.war file (using mvn package) and run it on Tomcat 9 on Linux
with endpoint:

```
http://myserver.com:8081/DataViewer/tspsPatentSearch
```

I get the infamous:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/DataViewer/tspsPatentSearch
```

My pom.xml file is:

```
`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"><modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.clarivate</groupId>
<artifactId>dataviewer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>dataviewer</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.clarivate.dataviewer.DvMain</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DS may need to remove for tomcat installation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

   <!-- Required to find ojdbc6, because Oracle don't make it available to maven-->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>codelds</id>
          <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>

<build>
    <finalName>DataViewer</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.clarivate.dataviewer.DvMain</mainClass>
            </configuration>    
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<description>TSPS data viewer</description>
```

In application.properties I have:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.servlet.path=/DataViewer
```

My main class is:

```
package com.clarivate.dataviewer;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication

public class DvMain extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    static Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("DS1A in main()");
        SpringApplication.run(DvMain.class, args);
        logger.info("DS1C finished.");
    }


    //@Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(DvMain.class);
     }  
}
```

My MainController.java has:

```
@GetMapping("/tspsPatentSearch")
public String tspsPatentSearch(Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("tspsPatent", new TspsPatent());

     return "tspsPatentSearch";                 
}
```

The war file unpacks fine and there are no errors. In catalina.out we have:

```
2018-10-04 12:09:09.954  INFO 12950 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/tspsPatentSearch],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.clarivate.dataviewer.controller.MainController.tspsPatentSearch(com.clarivate.dataviewer.model.TspsPatent,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
```

and no errors. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819277/issue-with-spring-there-was-an-unexpected-error-type-not-found-status-404) ie my package structure is correct and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482203/whitelabel-error-page-there-was-an-unexpected-error-type-not-found-status-404) ie my jsp's are in the correct location (data_viewer\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jsp)
and i'm now running short of ideas. Any help much appreciated

Edit: If I copy tspsPatentSearch.jsp into the war file top directory then tomcat finds it. So it looks like tomcat is ignoring:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
```

or not finding application.properties at all.

Comment: Have you tried http://myserver.com:8081/dataviewer/tspsPatentSearch?

Comment: try `http://localhost:8081/tspsPatentSearch`

Comment: Thanks , I've just tried these 2 endpoints and I get the same 404 error

Comment: Can you please post full DvMain class including all imports

Comment: @kj007 i've updated my original post

Comment: @benjamin I presume you mean myserver.com:8081/tspsPatentSearch . localhost is on my pc, the web app is running on linux server called myserver.com. Anyway I tried both and no luck

Comment: might be a noobie check, but just to make sure, have you verified that the tomcat server you've deployed to runs on port 8081?

Comment: @ConMan Yes. We had an old application that ran on 8081, I removed that and used the port for the DataViewer. If I reinstate the old application it still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `application.properties`:

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/
```

I've taken your sample code and, assuming you annotated your `MainController` simply as `@Controller`, put a deployment together. I changed a few things around, but I believe this was the bit that did it. I haven't been able to find any references explaining why it might be required by Tomcat, but I intend to keep looking. I'll update you if I find anything.

Edit:

I noticed some duplicate logging in Spring 2.0.2 related to this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13470

The problem appeared fixed in 2.0.4 therefore I upgraded.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Additionally, I removed the `server.servlet.contextPath=/` entry and *tada* I still can reach the Hello World jsp I set up. If upgrading is possible for you, maybe you could try that before adding something to `application.properties` which could be considered duplicated functionality. At least I can promise you a better logging experience.

Edit #2:

No smoking gun, so far, but these (from 2.0.4) could be related:

[Provide a consistent way to discover the primary DispatcherServlet's path](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13834)

[Dispatcher servlets with a custom servlet name are not found by the mappings endpoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/13211)

Nothing looked likely on a surface scan of 2.0.3. I'm going to give it a rest for now and give you a chance to try some stuff. Good luck!

Edit #3:

I'm sorry to continue suggesting you switch environment stuff around, but one difference I noted between what I tested and what you're working with is that you seem to be using Tomcat-9.0.0.M20 where as I was testing with [9.0.12](https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.12/).

Whether you want to upgrade or not, a few things to note and/or do:

1) Update your question with what you've got now if it's different than before. Include the `server.servlet.contextPath=/` in your `application.properties` just so anyone else looking can see what you've done.

2) The exclusion you have for `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` under `spring-boot-starter-web` doesn't appear to do anything - you can verify by comparing the output from running `mvn dependency:tree` before and after removal.

3) I'm not sure that your `spring-web` dependency is needed either, as that's brought in by default under the `spring-boot-starter`.

4) Now to your output. Spring Boot is coming up (note the banner) and your classes are being found and acted upon.

`catalina.out.DEBUG` also in your DS.log starting ~ 08:35:38.162

```
2018-10-12 09:30:17.322 DEBUG 55745 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Identified candidate component class: file [/data/apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M20/webapps/DataViewer/WEB-INF/classes/com/clarivate/dataviewer/controller/MainController.class]
2018-10-12 09:30:17.328 DEBUG 55745 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Identified candidate component class: file [/data/apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M20/webapps/DataViewer/WEB-INF/classes/com/clarivate/dataviewer/database/ReadFromDb.class]
2018-10-12 09:30:17.356 DEBUG 55745 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Identified candidate component class: file [/data/apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M20/webapps/DataViewer/WEB-INF/classes/com/clarivate/dataviewer/service/FileFuncs.class]
2018-10-12 09:30:17.357 DEBUG 55745 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Identified candidate component class: file [/data/apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M20/webapps/DataViewer/WEB-INF/classes/com/clarivate/dataviewer/service/StringFuncs.class]
...
2018-10-12 09:30:19.417  INFO 55745 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/tspsPatentSearch],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.clarivate.dataviewer.controller.MainController.tspsPatentSearch(com.clarivate.dataviewer.model.TspsPatent,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
2018-10-12 09:30:19.417  INFO 55745 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/tspsPatentSearch],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.clarivate.dataviewer.controller.MainController.tspsPatentSearch(org.springframework.ui.Model)
...
2018-10-12 09:30:19.769  INFO 55745 --- [           main] com.clarivate.dataviewer.DvMain          : Started DvMain in 3.125 seconds (JVM running for 5.845)
```

And I do indeed note the mapping to `/error` that's returned for your request at 09:32:11.

I find this strange:

```
2018-10-12 09:32:11.758 DEBUG 55745 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/DataViewer/DataViewer/error]
```

And it's different in DS.log:

```
2018-10-12 08:36:56.136 DEBUG 6992 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/DataViewer /error]
```

Specifically `/DataViewer/DataViewer/error` - have you tried requesting http://localhost:8081/DataViewer/DataViewer/tspsPatentSearch

In general this appears as though everything is coming up but there is a misconfiguration somewhere that isn't allowing a request to map to the handler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, im looking into it. Problem I have is that when I change the spring-boot-starter-parent version to 2.0.4 I get 2 sets of spring files, 2.0.2 AND 2.0.4 in my war file (but only the 2.0.4 in my build libraries). I've tried the Maven -> Update Project and various other stuff but so far no luck. Hopefully i'll fix it and get back to you.

Comment: I fixed the double spring files, but now http://localhost:8081/DataViewer/tspsPatentSearch (on Eclipse) which works fine with spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.2, returns 404 with spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.4. When I switch back to 2.0.2 it again works (on eclipse only)

Comment: @DS. I didn't do any testing last night within Eclipse so I've got nothing for you there. I didn't find a satisfactory way to introspect the process to see what's been mapped where. If it helps and if you haven't already done so, you can add `logging.level.root=DEBUG` to `application.properties` and get a flood of output which may contain info about JSP compilation (or absence thereof). I'm not positive about that syntax - I don't have my test bed from last night here with me.

Comment: I've turned debug on. The resulting eclipse log file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12KjPkSZkIsmXvubyV1AB2koX5tLfw9hU/view?usp=sharing . The bit before "DS1C" is when spring starts up, the bit after DS1C is when you try to hit endpoint http://localhost:8081/DataViewer/tspsPatentSearch. The file is 150K lines long!

Comment: Forget spring boot 2.0.4, it doesn't work. I tried 2.0.3, why not, and thats fine on Eclipse, but still not working on Tomcat 9. I've downloaded catalina.out.DEBUG to  : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UW75qWc025rLIdY2BuQqCJ8jBZwlc4Vi and catalina.out.INFO to https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kKwy8vMV8ZDNy2Wj6IjvxVKwuKcqiVrh There is no "DS1C" in either, so my main class is not found. In catalina.out.DEBUG everything after 9:32 is from trying to hit  http://myserver.com:8081/DataViewer/tspsPatentSearch

Comment: myserver.com:8081/DataViewer/DataViewer/tspsPatentSearch works :), not sure why yet. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DS. I saw you updated your question! This `server.servlet.path=/DataViewer` is why you've got nested mappings. Change `/DataViewer` to `/` and you're golden.

Comment: @jon_sampson when I do that it doesn't work on Eclipse. The first "DataViewer" in the myserver.com:8081/DataViewer/DataViewer/tspsPatentSearch end point comes from the war file name. If I change the war file name to ROOT.war then the war name is ignored and myserver.com:8081/DataViewer/tspsPatentSearch works on Eclipse AND on the external tomcat.  This however is not ideal as we have multiple war files on the same tomcat server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181770/discussion-between-jon-sampson-and-ds).

Answer (score 1):

To confirm.
Tomcat adds the war file name to the end point, so if we create DataViewerX.war and set :

```
server.servlet.path=/DataViewer
```

then the end point when running on an external tomcat is:

```
myServer.com/DataViewerX/DataViewer/tspsPatentSearch
```

but when we run on Eclispe, using the source code, then the end point is:

```
http://localhost:8081/DataViewer/tspsPatentSearch
```

which is a bit annoying but not a major problem. A way round this is to call the war file ROOT.war, then tomcat ignores the war file name and the 2 end points are the same, but I have multiple war files in the webapps dir so this solution isn't acceptable for me.
If anyone know's a way to allow the 2 end points to be the same then please say so, but it's not that important.