# Error deploying the example application (Spring Boot 1.3.4, JSP, WAR Packaging) at Pivotal Cloud Foundry using STS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, np-spring

I followed [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/10/15/the-spring-boot-dashboard-in-sts-part-2-working-with-cloud-foundry) to use *Boot Dashboard* to deploy the [Spring example application](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/np-spring-tutorial) to Pivotal Cloud Foundry. The example application is a Spring Boot application (1.3.2.RELEASE), uses JSP and has WAR packaging.

The application seemed to start ok, but then the home page was blank. Trying cURL, I saw the following output:

[image]

But, when I deploy the application using command line:

```
cf push np-spring-tutorial -p spring-tutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

The application got deployed and is running well.

So, is it that the Boot Dashboard way of deployment to PWS isn't yet supporting WAR files with JSPs? I have tried before JSP less JAR files deployment with Boot Dashboard, and they worked well.

**Update:**

As recommended by *Sanjay Rawat*, I updated Spring Boot version to `1.3.4`, and also now have a `manifest.yml` as below:

```
---
applications:
- name: np-spring-tutorial
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
  path: target/spring-tutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
  env:
    application_url: http://np-spring-tutorial.cfapps.io
  services:
   - np-spring-tutorial-db
  timeout: 180
```

By hit and trial, I noticed that the only setting actually required was `path: target/spring-tutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`.

Now the application is running, and I'm able to see the pages. However, when starting the application, the following error appears on the console:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vcap/app/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vcap/app/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

Comment: Is it an Spring Boot application? If yes, do mention the Boot version number.

Comment: Yes it's a Spring Boot application. The version is 1.3.2.RELEASE. (updated the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use - [CF Java Build-packs](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack).

Run below command :

`cf push webAppSpaceName -p spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jsp-1.3.3.RELEASE.war -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git`

Since you are using Spring-Boot-1.3.2.RELEASE you might face this [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938716/jsp-with-jstl-not-working-on-tomcat-8-in-a-spring-boot-application/36118485#36118485).

**Update:**

More info on Build packs:

> Buildpacks provide framework and runtime support for your applications. Buildpacks typically examine user-provided artifacts to determine what dependencies to download and how to configure applications to communicate with bound services.

You don't have to explicitly mention which Buildpack to use, Cloud Foundry automatically detects which buildpack is required and installs it on the Droplet Execution Agent (DEA) where the application needs to run.
[Reference](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/).

But it is good to specify so that CF uses the latest Build pack.

You can specify the Build pack in `manifest.yml` file in your project and then deploy using Dashboard:

`buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack`

However, CF CLI has more options and features.

Comment: Just `cf push np-spring-tutorial -p spring-tutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` seems to be working, as I have mentioned in the question. How is your command better than this? Does the `Boot  Dashboard` not yet support WARs with JSPs, then?

Comment: Boot Dashboard has nothing to do with WAR Support. It is just a plugin for CF CLI to make deployment easier. Although it doesn't provide all options and features that CLI do.

`-b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git` defines a Build-Pack for your application which you can also define in `manifest.yml` file in your project. 

The error/issue you have is with your project configuration, have you look at the Issue I mentioned. Updated my answer for more info on build packs.

Comment: PS: I tested and deployed this [Spring-Boot-JSP](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jsp) app in PCF Dev and it is working fine.

Comment: Did you use the Boot Dashboard of STS?

Comment: Yes, I just tried the Boot Dashboard way. It is also working fine. As I said use the `manifest.yml` file, like one [here](https://gist.github.com/RawSanj/8f66b229f8b4d992172708d0e7e9f698).

Comment: Thanks, Sanjay. The application is now working, and I've updated my question with the details. In summary, I found that `path: target/spring-tutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` did the trick. But, now I'm getting a different, SLF4J, error. Accepting your answer, though. Do you have any idea on how to fix the SLF4J error? Should I create a separate ticket for that?

Comment: A separate question would attract more attention. Is the Git repo you mentioned in the question throwing this error? I tried to deploy that but I was getting persistence errors coz of missing configuration, I'll try again when I get time.

Comment: I created a `tmp1` branch and removed MySQL, so that persistent errors won't come. Have put the details in another ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108814/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings-error-when-deploying-the-sp