# "SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings" error when deploying the Spring example application to Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring, spring-boot, np-spring

I'm trying to deploy the [tmp1 branch](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/np-spring-tutorial/tree/tmp1) of the *Spring example application (A Spring Boot 1.3.4 application using JSP and having WAR packaging)* to Pivotal Cloud Foundry, using STS Boot Dashboard. I have created a manifest.yml file, looking as below:

```
---
applications:
- name: np-spring-tutorial
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
  path: target/spring-tutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
  env:
    application_url: http://np-spring-tutorial.cfapps.io
  timeout: 180
```

The application gets deployed and seems to be running well; I'm able to view the pages. However, when starting it gives :SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings" error. Here is the log:

```
[9 May, 2016 11:18:31 AM - Boot Dashboard] - Creating application: np-spring-tutorial
[9 May, 2016 11:18:38 AM - Boot Dashboard] - Verifying that the application was created successfully: np-spring-tutorial
Updated app with guid 7a95bd52-1c14-461b-a6df-59aeb7ba285a ({"environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})
[9 May, 2016 11:19:08 AM - Boot Dashboard] - Generating archive for application: np-spring-tutorial
[9 May, 2016 11:19:08 AM - Boot Dashboard] - Uploading archive to Cloud Foundry for application: np-spring-tutorial
[9 May, 2016 11:19:57 AM - Boot Dashboard] - Archive uploaded to Cloud Foundry for application: np-spring-tutorial
[9 May, 2016 11:20:02 AM - Boot Dashboard] - Starting application: np-spring-tutorial
[9 May, 2016 11:20:09 AM - Boot Dashboard] - Checking if the application is running. Please wait...
Updated app with guid 7a95bd52-1c14-461b-a6df-59aeb7ba285a ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
Creating container
Successfully created container
Downloading app package...
Downloaded app package (45.5M)
Staging...
-----> Java Buildpack Version: 78c3d0a | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#78c3d0a
-----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_91-unlimited-crypto from https://download.run.pivotal.io/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_91-unlimited-crypto.tar.gz (1.9s)
       Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (1.1s)
-----> Downloading Open JDK Like Memory Calculator 2.0.2_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/memory-calculator/trusty/x86_64/memory-calculator-2.0.2_RELEASE.tar.gz (0.0s)
       Memory Settings: -Xss1M -Xmx768M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=104857K -Xms768M -XX:MetaspaceSize=104857K
-----> Downloading Container Customizer 1.0.0_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/container-customizer/container-customizer-1.0.0_RELEASE.jar (0.0s)
Exit status 0
Staging complete
Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
Uploading build artifacts cache...
Uploading droplet...
Uploaded build artifacts cache (45.4M)
Uploaded droplet (91.1M)
Creating container
Successfully created container
Starting health monitoring of container
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vcap/app/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vcap/app/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.EnsureExceptionHandling.process(Lch/qos/logback/core/Context;Lch/qos/logback/core/pattern/Converter;)V
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.PatternLayoutBase.start(PatternLayoutBase.java:85)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder.start(PatternLayoutEncoder.java:28)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.BasicConfigurator.configure(BasicConfigurator.java:50)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:164)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:140)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:119)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:328)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:280)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:191)
    at com.naturalprogrammer.spring.tutorial.NpSpringTutorialApplication.main(NpSpringTutorialApplication.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.EnsureExceptionHandling.process(Lch/qos/logback/core/Context;Lch/qos/logback/core/pattern/Converter;)V
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.PatternLayoutBase.start(PatternLayoutBase.java:85)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder.start(PatternLayoutEncoder.java:28)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackConfigurator.start(LogbackConfigurator.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.DefaultLogbackConfiguration.consoleAppender(DefaultLogbackConfiguration.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.DefaultLogbackConfiguration.apply(DefaultLogbackConfiguration.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadDefaults(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:262)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.naturalprogrammer.spring.tutorial.NpSpringTutorialApplication.main(NpSpringTutorialApplication.java:14)
    ... 6 more
Exit status 0
Exit status 0
App instance exited with guid 7a95bd52-1c14-461b-a6df-59aeb7ba285a payload: {"instance"=>"3c98e26d-7714-45b8-6152-df1ae08c2025", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Codependent step exited\n* cancelled\n* cancelled", "crash_count"=>1, "crash_timestamp"=>1462773044776529510, "version"=>"8cf24bda-13e6-49a6-8b52-906440c1b780"}
Creating container
Successfully created container
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vcap/app/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vcap/app/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.4.RELEASE)
2016-05-09 05:50:52.875  INFO 29 --- [           main] pertySourceApplicationContextInitializer : Adding 'cloud' PropertySource to ApplicationContext
2016-05-09 05:50:52.963  INFO 29 --- [           main] nfigurationApplicationContextInitializer : Adding cloud service auto-reconfiguration to ApplicationContext
2016-05-09 05:50:52.978  INFO 29 --- [           main] c.n.s.t.NpSpringTutorialApplication      : Starting NpSpringTutorialApplication on ip3ju5q5j6m with PID 29 (/home/vcap/app/WEB-INF/classes started by vcap in /home/vcap/app)
...
2016-05-09 05:51:07.749  INFO 29 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-05-09 05:51:08.376  INFO 29 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
Container became healthy
2016-05-09 05:51:08.720  INFO 29 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-05-09 05:51:10.014  INFO 29 --- [           main] c.n.s.t.NpSpringTutorialApplication      : Started NpSpringTutorialApplication in 18.612 seconds (JVM running for 19.599)
[9 May, 2016 11:21:22 AM - Boot Dashboard] - Application appears to have started - np-spring-tutorial
```

Any idea how to fix this? (This question has originated from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089561/error-deploying-the-example-application-spring-boot-1-3-4-jsp-war-packaging/37093413?noredirect=1#comment61757433_37093413))

**Update**

As recommended by Gemini, checking the WAR, I indeed see two logback-classic-x.x.x.jars:

[image]

However, looking at the maven dependency tree, I see only the 1.1.7 version of logback, as below:

[image]

So, what could be going wrong? Maybe the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is doing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be only one implementation of slf4j in your classpath. Please check your project dependencies and remove one of them.

From what you've posted, there are two jars `jar:file:/home/vcap/app/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar` and `jar:file:/home/vcap/app/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar` in your application, which should be mistake.

You can just keep one of them and remove the one you don't want to use, for example, keep the newer and remove the older. It should be fine.

If you are using maven to management your dependencies, you can check the full dependencies and make sure there is only one of them exist(exclude the one you do not want to use). If they are added manually, you can manually remove it and repackage your application. It'll work.

Comment: The application only has 1.1.7, as clear by checking pom dependencies. It's working fine when run locally. However, the problem appears when deploying to PWS through Boot Dashboard (but not through CLI).

Comment: Have you ever checked your jar or war? Are there multiple `logback-classic-x.x.x.jar`? As you can see, both of them are located in `WEB-INF/lib/`.

Comment: It could be imported by other dependency, command `mvn dependency:tree` will show all dependencies.

Comment: Hi Gemini, I've appended to my question the findings based on your suggestions.

Comment: Would you please post the output of command `mvn dependency:tree` information here? In intellijidea, you can right click the content of `pom.xml` and click `Maven->Show Dependencies ...` will display all dependencies for you. You can press `Ctrl+F` to find all what you want. So I guess command `mvn dependency:tree` will show them too. By the way, in eclipse you can specify additional `jar` as library, please try to check all these libraries too.

Comment: Additionally, you can right click the project and choose `Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries` to check all dependencies.

Comment: I've already pasted an image showing the maven dependency tree, filtered by `logback`, as shown in STS (Eclipse). Also, I just saw `Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries` and confirmed that only `1.1.7` is there in the classpath. BTW, in the first line of the question, there's a link to the project at GitHub.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111425/discussion-between-gemini-keith-and-sanjay).